# How to define models without use Sequelize ? (Node.JS with MySQL)

Tags: mysql, node.js, model, sequelize.js

I work with Node.JS and MySQL with "mysql" package.
Is there is a way to define models with class ?? 
I read a lot and all opinion say i need sequellize for this.
In angular i use data model like this:

```
export class Stage {
    public name: string;
    public consultation: string;
    public approval: string;
    public stageOrder: number;
}
```

Is there is a way to make it work in nodejs? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you need to use `sequellize` and defined a class in this way:

```js
           const Stage = sequelize.define('stage', {
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false
  },
  consultation: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
   
  },
 approval: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING
   
  },
 stageOrder: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
   
  }
}, {
  // options
});
```

You can read the documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getting-started.html).

Comment: Sequelize can be install and work with "mysql" package or it replace it?

Comment: yes , you can use MySql. If you need more details , take a look at the following linke: